# Persistence in hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about Spring and Hibernate and that is, if for example I want to persist two entities at the same time, such as Customer and Address, that when a customer is registered, their address is automatically saved as well.

It is that the address is retrieved from an address api external to my application and I want that information to be saved in the Address entity when the client registers.

My entities are the following:

Customer :

```java
public class Customer{
     
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")
    private String nombre;

    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")
    @Column(name = "apellido_paterno")
    private String apellidoPaterno;

    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")
    @Column(name = "apellido_materno")
    private String apellidoMaterno;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")
    private String telefono;
 
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
    private Address address;
}
```

Address:

```java
public class Address{

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
 
    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")         
    private String calle;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació") 
    private String colonia;
    
    @NotNull(message = "no puede estar vació")
    @Column(name = "no_exterior")   
    private Integer noExterior; 
 
    @Column(name = "no_interior")   
    private Integer noInterior;
 
    @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació") 
    private String municipio;
    
    @NotNull(message = "no puede estar vació")
    private Integer cp; 
    
     @NotBlank(message = "no puede estar vació")    
    private String estado;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adress")
    private List<Customer> customer;
}
```

Since I have it, the address must already be created so that it can be associated with the client, however, I want that when the client enters their data, including the address, they are created at the same time and the association is maintained.

Comment: What you are looking for is `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` on @ManyToOne annotation in your Customer class. See it in action here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types#2-cascadetypepersist

Answer (score 0):

When you persist the Entity "Customer" you should create a object Customer and a object Address, and set to the Customer the Address object and add to the Customer list in Address object, the object Customer. I mean, you should do it in your business logic layer, or your service.